# ActiveMQ multi consumer stops consuming when one consumer crashed

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

We have 3 servers configured in a single ensemble. All the fuse servers are part of a single fabric. Check the current deign as below,

3 root containers ( ROOT 1, 2 & 3)
Every Root containers have 2 child containers ( one for Active MQ broker and another for camel container).

> ROOT 1 - AMQ 1 & CAMEL 1
>
> ROOT 2 - AMQ 2 & CAMEL 2
>
> ROOT 3 - AMQ 3 & CAMEL 3

AMQ 1,2 & 3 are part of same broker group. That means at a time only one AMQ instance is active and others are for failover.

CAMEL 1,2 & 3 are processing the messages from the AMQ.

Problem :

We processed 1000 messages in AMQ which was consumed by all the consumers i.e. CAMEL 1,2 & 3.
But when any of the consumers (either CAMEL 1,2 or 3) were killed by using kill -9  then the messages present in the AMQ are stuck and not processed at all by the remaining running consumers.

Check below configuration we have in the blueprint for ActiveMQComponent,

```
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory" id="activeMqXaConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="discovery:(fabric:test-broker-group)?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000&amp;jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=0&amp;jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true&amp;alwaysSessionAsync=true"/>
    <property name="trustAllPackages" value="true"/>
    <property name="xaAckMode" value="2"/>
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="false"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.JcaPooledConnectionFactory" id="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="name" value="activemq.default"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTxManager"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activeMqXaConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="50"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="86400000"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.GenericResourceManager"
    id="amqresourceManager" init-method="recoverResource">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTxManager"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activeMqXaConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="resourceName" value="activemq.default"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" id="activemq">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory"/>
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="springJtaTxManager"/>
            <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
            <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE"/>
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
            <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<service interface="org.apache.camel.Component" ref="activemq"/>
```

Note : not using topics. only queues

We also tried AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE. But still have the same behavior.

Expected - should process the messages even if any of the consumers were killed.
Actual - AMQ messages are stuck in the queue.

Comment: This looks like an issue with 1 session shared accros all your consumers. In that case, a message not acknowledged will block the consumption until expiration if any defined. Read http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-activemq-to-hold-100s-of-millions-of-queue-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. I first thought of prefetch sizes, but you already set them to zero. I would suggest to run through the scenario again. When the described situation arrives

1. check the broker logs
2. inspect your consumers and the queue through JMX (state, memory etc)

Perhaps it is also worth a try to temporarily remove the transaction manager to be sure this issue does not arise because of transactions.